# How to trace run time console logs in ec2 instance

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2

I use the AWS SSM send-command AWS-RunShellScript through the AWS command line interface to send commands to a number of EC2 instances. The command runs the JS script which will generate run-time console logs (JS); is there a way to view it in EC2?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use Amazon CloudWatch Logs to monitor, store, and access your
> log files from Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances. CloudWatch Logs enables
> you to centralize the logs from all of your systems, applications, and
> AWS services that you use, in a single, highly scalable service.

To install Cloudwatch agent and configure your cloudwatch agent, Kindly [refer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)